# Problem with installing bumblebee in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, nvidia, dpkg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am getting the following error while installing bumblebee in Ubuntu 14.10:

```
rajamalw@AMAL-WORKSTATION:~$ sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bumblebee-nvidia : Depends: bumblebee (= 3.2.1-5) but 3.2.1-90~trustyppa1 is to be  installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`

Any one help me to fix this

Answer (score 3):

The conflicting version `3.2.1-90~trustyppa1` is coming from the [stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

Unless you need some specific feature from that version you could remove the PPA and use the version that comes with *utopic* by default:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia
```